# Linker error when inlining function

Tags: c++, inline, linker-errors

I have made a function which looks like this:

```
//hpp
extern std::array<CPlayer, MAX_PLAYERS> PlayerArray;
inline CPlayer& Player(int playerid);
//cpp
std::array<CPlayer, MAX_PLAYERS> PlayerArray;
inline CPlayer& Player(int playerid)
{
    return PlayerArray[playerid];
}
```

but when doing this I get a linker error saying:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CPlayer & __cdecl Player(int)" (?Player@@YAAAVCPlayer@@H@Z)
```

However when I remove the `inline` keyword, everything compiles fine.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function get's inlined and effectively removed from the binary as a stand alone function.

Move the implementation to header to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

From [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/where-to-put-inline-keyword.html) best practice, if function body definition is outside `class`, then remove `inline` keyword from declaration.

```
class Foo {
public:
  void method();  ← best practice: don't put the inline keyword here
  ...
};

inline void Foo::method()  ← best practice: put the inline keyword here
{ ... }
```